# Is there a 2-way proportion comparison in R with usage like prop.test?

Tags: r, statistics, two-way

I am hoping to compare proportions from an experiment with a two-by-two factorial design. I use R for my stats.

I know how to compare two proportions, or do an ANOVA-like test on many proportions, by using prop.test.

For example,

```
num_positive = c(10, 30)
num_total = c(100,180)
prop.test(x = num_positive, num_total)
```

or for the one-way-ANOVA-like situation:

```
num_positive = c(10, 30, 80)
num_total = c(100,180, 200)
prop.test(x = num_positive, num_total)
```

But I don't know how to do this with a two-way situation. prop.test doesn't accept any sort of model structure and the data are proportion data so don't make sense to be analyzed using an ANOVA.

Ideally, I'd want a function that does something like this:

```
num_positive = c(10, 30, 80, 100)
num_total = c(100,180, 200, 200)
factorA = c("A","A","B","B")
factorZ = c("Z","Y","Z","Y")

prop.test(cbind(num_positive, num_total) ~ factorA * factorZ)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do exactly what you are thinking of, as far as I know - i.e. to compare proportions in this way.

However, you can use cbind to combine the proportions into one variable, which you then include in a generalized linear model (glm), e.g.

```
y <- cbind(num_positive, num_total)
```

Then you can compare your y variable against your factors, e.g.

```
model <- glm(y ~ factorA * factorZ, binomial)
```

I suggest reading up on the correct link function to use in the glm, also consider whether to enter your factors as a categorical (levels) variable.